# tclodbc how to insert values with sql statements coming from a file

Tags: file, odbc, tcl

I'm in the process of modifying some tcl code and the author had defined sql statements in the code.

I've not included the database connection code or the package require tclodbc statements but this is really all of the flow for my test case.

```
set query "alter table dbo.customer add constraint customer_pk primary key (c_custkey) with (maxdop=$maxdop)"
set maxdop 2

    if {[catch {db $query} err] } {
        puts "SQL ERROR"
        puts [format "ERROR is ===\n%s\n===" $err]
        }
```

However I would like to make this a little more generic and read the sql from
a file. (This way I can experiment with the SQL without editing the program)

So I tried:

```
set silly_id [open silly.sql" r]
set sql_in   [gets $silly.sql]  

    if {[catch {db $sql_in} err] } {
        puts "SQL ERROR"
        puts [format "ERROR is ===\n%s\n===" $err]
    }
```

I've tried just about every combination of eval and subst that I can imagine
and still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are looking for is this:

```
# Correct pattern for reading from a file
set silly_id [open "silly.sql" r]
set sql_in   [read $silly_id]
close $silly_id

# Do substitutions in the SQL before evaluation
if {[catch {db [subst $sql_in]} err] } {
    puts "SQL ERROR"
    puts [format "ERROR is ===\n%s\n===" $err]
}
```

---

### But wait!

That code has a *big* problem in that it is horribly vulnerable to problems in the value of `$maxdop` (e.g., if it has an unexpected value because it has come from an untrusted user). In general, you should instead use parameterized queries. This isn't too critical for an `ALTER TABLE` (where you shouldn't really be using any info from a user) but with `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DROP` you need to be ever so careful. It's much easier to get parameterized statements right; TclODBC supports them too, as you can see from this example in the [documentation](http://www.dgroth.de/tcl8.4.4/databases/tclodbc2.3/REFERENC.HTM):

```
% db statement s "select fullname from article where id=132" 
s 
% s 
{FullName132} 
% db statement s2 "select fullname from article where id1=?" INTEGER
s2 
% s2 132 
{FullName132}
```

Comment: If you're reading from many files, it might be easiest to factor out that file reading stanza into its own procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're really just asking how to open and read a file in TCL, right? You seem to have the SQL part working fine. If so, it's as simple as this (taken from [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367))

```
     set fp [open "somefile" r]
     set file_data [read $fp]
     close $fp
```